# How to set max width and max height in React Lottie SVG animation with tailwind css and react?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, lottie

I am wondering if there is any way to control react-lottie max width and max height?
I have a simple lottie component like this

```
        <div className={s.animation}>
                <Lottie options={defaultOptions} />
            </div>
```

and my tailwind css to control lottie svg

```
.animation {
    @apply mt-6;
    @apply max-w-[600px] max-h-[450px];
}

.formContainer {
    @apply flex flex-col items-center;
    @apply mt-5;
}
```

and my defaultOptions are

```
    const defaultOptions = {
        loop: true,
        autoplay: true,
        animationData: lottie,
        rendererSettings: {
            preserveAspectRatio: 'xMaxYMax slice'
        }
    }
```

Current code adjust max and min size of lottie but it stacks in the left (start) side even if we add `flex items-center` css property.

Is there any way I can align lottie animation & set min-max size of the svg both together at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

give these class for him : "w-full h-full"